# python read a file on web to get variable

Tags: python, file, url, web, get

I have a file on my web server and i want my python script to read this file then import it as a library to have the variable from this file , but i tried to use urlparse but i was not able to do the mission exactly .

My code :-

```
.....
from urllib.parse import urlparse
moregc = urlparse('http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/moregc')
from moregc import cde
if cde == securecode:
    .....
```

I was using this code to read it from a local file and it was perfect in the job :-

```
from reg import cde
if cde == securecode:
```

the point is this file will be as online regfile to protect my program from being used without permission .

Comment: But if your users really want to use your program without permission, can't they just open the source code, see the file is being downloaded from `"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/moregc"`, and download it themselves? Then they can use it however they want, no permission required.

Comment: the code is compiled to pyc , also the file on the internet along with it .. and if the user has copied it outside i can remove the file from the web server and the program will be disconnected ... Anyway my users in our local area is not too fine with python codes , I've made all the security steps to protect the program but the last step is this one

Answer (score 0):

How about, instead of downloading a module which you then import, you just read the page directly?

```
data = urllib.urlopen("http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/moregc").read()
if "allowed" in data:
    #continue with program
else:
    print "sorry, you are no longer authorized to run this script"
```

Then you only need to put the word "allowed" on your moregc page when you want to allow the script, and remove the word when you don't want to allow it.